# symfony 3.4 installer downloads an html file

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, symfony-3.4, ubuntu-21.04

I tried to install symfony 3.4 on ubuntu 21.04 following the doc

```
 sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
 sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
 sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

but I get this error(in spanish)

```
/usr/local/bin/symfony: línea 1: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `newline'
/usr/local/bin/symfony: línea 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

the downloaded file its html file, if it is the the official doc and it doesn't work what else can I do?

Comment: Looks like those docs are outdated. https://symfony.com/installer is giving a 404. Symfony 3.4 is no longer maintained, so they've probably removed the installer. Follow the directions here instead: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

Comment: Why do you want to install Symfony 3.4? It's end of life.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [an article on Symfony's blog](https://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-the-symfony-installer):

> Like other announcements we have made recently, this blog post officially announces that the Symfony Installer won't be developed anymore. Bugs will still be fixed and its end of life is scheduled for November 2020 as this is when Symfony 3.4 will not be supported anymore.

---

Better start a new project with a more recent version of Symfony, for example using

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name
```

or any other way listed in [Symfony's documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html)